# send data throung ip works in local ip and not work on internet ip

Tags: java, networking

I use the below code to send data through a network, I work on local network, but when I give the internet ip of the receiver device doesn't work. Means no data is received and doesn't give any exception.

```
InetAddress inet=InetAddress.getByName("46.209.243.22");
DatagramSocket socket=new DatagramSocket();
DatagramPacket packect=new DatagramPacket("ali".getBytes(), 3, inet, 400);
socket.send(packect);
```

What's the problem and How can I solve it?

Comment: Please refresh this page, it's not android question.

Comment: Make sure your NAT on the receiving end is not eating your traffic.

Comment: "46.209.243.22" is likely a router, and has IP addresses assigned "behind" it (your local IP addresses). If your port is not forwarded to the correct local IP you will not be able to connect to the machine.